# How do I adjust the height of a particular listview when the content is more in android?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code to display the content from `firebase`. But when the content is more, '..' will be displayed as shown in the image.
How do I make it to adjust the height automatically and display the full content instead of ..?

Screen-shot of the activity

[image]

```
Public class InstituteMessageBoard extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_institute_message_board);

        insTool = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.institute_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(insTool);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Institute Notice");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        DatabaseReference classPostRef = dRef.child("admin").child("classPost");
        classPostRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String post = dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue(String.class);
                    list.add(post);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default `ArrayAdapter` with `simple_dropdown_item_1line` this layout. 
It has single `Textview` with `android:singleLine="true"`  cause of which data is showing in one line only.

Switch to custom `ArrayAdapter` and create `row` layout as per your requirement.

[How to create custom array adapter?](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

instead of,

```
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
```